# Selector of one item of UIToolbar doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

read the following code:

```
// Creiamo la toolbar sotto
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 372, 320, 44)];
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgImpostazioniToolbar.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *pulsanteImpostazioni = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
[pulsanteImpostazioni setTarget:self];
[pulsanteImpostazioni setAction:@selector(prova)];
[imageView release];
UIBarButtonItem *spaziatore = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
NSArray *buttons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:spaziatore, pulsanteImpostazioni, spaziatore, nil];
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[buttons release];
```

I can see correctly my image but when I try to touch it nothing happen.
I didn't set correctly the selector of "pulsanteImpostazioni"?
Thanks

P.s. "prova" contain only a NSLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution in this mode:

```
    UIButton *pulsanteImpostazioni = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[pulsanteImpostazioni setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
[pulsanteImpostazioni setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgImpostazioniToolbar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[pulsanteImpostazioni addTarget:self action:@selector(prova) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *pulsanteImpostazioni = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:pulsanteImpostazioni];
```

Thanks anyway for your answers =)

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`[pulsanteImpostazioni setAction:@selector(prova:)];`

The colon at the end of the selector name matters.